# How can I use Azurite in a command line application?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azurite

For my unit tests I want to use Azurite to create & verify BLOBs. [The instructions only show how to do this for an ASP.NET app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#running-azurite-from-an-aspnet-project) How can I do it for a command line app?

I tried running Azurite from the command line and got this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator>azuri
te
Azurite Blob service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10000
Exit due to unhandled error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\__azurite_db_blob__.json~'

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator>
```

**Update:** And now I'm getting the following. My Blazor app is not presently running, but was 30 minutes ago.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator>azurite
Azurite Blob service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10000
Exit due to unhandled error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:10000

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator>
```

And now my unit tests run and can hit Azurite. So it looks like running it from my Blazor app starts it and keeps it running. So that is a solution.

But is there a way to have the command line app start it up if needed?

My configuration is (so shouldn't need any credentials):

```
 "AzureStorageKey": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
```

Note: Azurite is running fine automatically starting when I run my Blazor app from Visual Studio.

Comment: This looks like an issue with permissions. Can you try by running using instructions provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#workspace-path? Or try to run in elevated command prompt?

Comment: @GauravMantri Do you have any idea which specifically I should use? I've read that through twice and I'm sure it makes sense to someone familiar with all that. But I'm lost as I've never touched anything having to do with permissions around anything running on my PC. My world of permissions is setting them in Azure or for a database.

Comment: It’s the permission of creating files in the directory where you’re running Azurite.

Comment: @GauravMantri Ok, that makes sense. But how do I tell it that it can create files?

Comment: You can specify another directory (e.g. `C:\temp`) for these files when starting Azurite (`azurite -l c:\temp`) or open command prompt with elevated permissions (something like `Run as Administrator`).

Comment: @DavidThielen -  Did you get a chance to look into the below solution.

Comment: @Harshitha What I'm doing is running my Blazor app before running the unit tests. That gets it loaded up. Not a perfect solution, but it works.

Comment: So you are running azurite inside a blazor app.

Comment: I'm doing both. My Blazor app automatically starts it. That's always been fine. My unit tests also try to access it. They do not auto-start it and depend on the Blazor app to have started it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I got the same error when I run the `azurite` from the path which you have mentioned.

[image]

Thank you @Gaurav Mantri for the comments.

From this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#running-azurite-from-the-command-line), it is clear that no need to go to the `Azure Storage Emulator` path to run `azurite`.

Open the CMD, run the command `azurite.exe` along with the path as shown below.

As I am using the Community edition, I have copied the path of it.

```cs
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"
```

[image]

***With Professional Edition:***
[image]

I have tried the same by opening the command prompt as an Administrator as well.

I got the same output.
[image]

As mentioned in the doc, I even tried with the temp path as well.

[image]

No need to go to the Azure Storage Emulator path and run `azurite`.

Instead open the command prompt and run the`azurite.exe` along with complete path.

In your case, run

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"
```

> ```
> Exit due to unhandled error: >listen EADDRINUSE: address >already in use 127.0.0.1:10000
> ```

If one instance is running and you run the same command again in new instance, you will get this error.

I have opened the new cmd  prompt and executed the same command again, even I got the same error.

[image]